# Using energy method to solve SHM of an object through a tunnel dug through the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, harmonic-oscillator, earth

I want to figure out the time period when an object performs simple harmonic motion by passing through a hole through the Earth.
[image]

Let the mass of Earth be $M_0$. Therefore, mass of Earth at radius $r$ is $M_e(r)=M_0\big(\frac{r}{R_e}\big)^3$.

Taking the mid-point to be the reference point, potential energy
$$U = -\frac{G M_0 md^3}{R_e^3d} + \frac{G M_0 mr^3}{R_e^3r} = \frac{GM_0m}{R_e^3}(r^2-d^2)$$
$$\therefore U = \frac{GM_0m}{R_e^3}y^2$$

If the velocity of the object at the given point is $v$, then, $$K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Thus, $E = U + K$,
$$E = \frac{GM_0m}{R_e^3}y^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$\implies \frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{GM_0m}{R_e^3}\bigg(2y\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}m(2v)\bigg(\frac{dv}{dt}\bigg)$$

Since mechanical energy remains constant in a conservative force field, $\frac{dE}{dt}=0$. Thus,
$$\frac{2GM_0m}{R_e^3}y\frac{dy}{dt}+m\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0$$
$$m\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg[\frac{2GM_0y}{R_e^3}+\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\bigg]=0$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-\frac{2GM_0}{R_e^3}y = -\omega_0^2y$$

Thus, angular frequency $\omega_0^2=\frac{2GM_0}{R_e^3}=\frac{2g}{R_e}.$ Therefore, time period, $$T = 2\pi \bigg(\frac{R_e}{2g}\bigg)^{1/2}$$

But, my book says that the time period $2\pi \bigg(\frac{R_e}{g}\bigg)^{1/2}$. Why am I getting a factor of half in my answer? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second term in potential energy expression is wrong. To calculate potential energy inside the earth, calculate the work done to bring the mass from $infinity$ to the point under consideration. The work done to bring up to the surface is dependence on the parameters of the Earth and would vanish on differentiation. So we leave that.

Now work done from surface to the inner point is $-\int \frac{GM_emr}{R_e^3} dr$. Clearly it would bring a factor of two in the denominator on integration and would solve your problem.